# Stopping image to resize and hiding bottom scrollbar

Tags: html, css

How can you stop image being resized by the browser? I want image to have certain width so I'm using `<img src='src' style='width: certain_widthpx' />`.
However when you resize the browser width, the scrollbar in the bottom appears which I don't want. How can I stop that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide a simplified version of your DOM in the question. Assuming parent of `img` is `body`
Add this css rule to the parent.

```
body{
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: as per your answer, the horizontal scrollbar at the bottom of browser will not appear but at a cost, for view-ports narrower than the image's width, certain part of image will get cut-off as you're not allowing the browser to display the complete image, instead you're hiding the image that is in overflow. 
I would suggest you should use "overflow-x: auto/scroll" on the immediate parent of the image. This way you can scroll your container to see the complete image and prevent the browser to show horizontal scrollbar at the bottom, if view-port is narrower than the image's width.

Answer (score 0):

You should specify image minimum width and height:

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/800x800" style="min-width: 800px; min-height: 800px;" width="800" height="800" />
```

Answer (score 0):

As you asked you want your image not to be resized by the browser, browsers resize contents within a window based on the `view-port`. Every time you'll try to resize your browser, `view-port` will change, so to maintain the user's viewing experience content gets resized. Now as you showed `<img src='src' style='width: certain_widthpx' />`, here you're trying to give your image a fixed width that means you're restricting the `view-port` to hold the image at this fixed width and hence at `view-ports` lesser than your image's width, horizontal scrollbars appear. If you really want your image to be of that fixed width then you should contain it within an another holder and give an `overflow-x` to be `scroll`/`auto`.

```
Like this:

<div style="overflow-x: auto;'>
   <img src='src' style='width: certain_widthpx' />
</div>

OR there is one more way and that is CSS way

<div class="holder">
   <img src='src' />
</div>

CSS:

.holder { overflow-x: auto; }
.holder img { width: certain_widthpx; }

In above solution your image will hold that fixed width but the holder will adjust itself as per the view-port and the point where your image's width will be greater than the view-port holder will start showing horizontal scrollbars, but the browser window will not.
```